# Is the nullity of composition of linear transforms over non-finite dimensional still <= sum of nullities (if they're of finite nullity)?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}$ $\DeclareMathOperator{\Nul}{Null}$ I know that if $V$ were finite dimensional we'd have for $A,B \in \End(V)$ that $\Nul(AB) \leq \Nul(A) + \Nul(B)$. Does this still hold if $V$ is not finitely dimensional, but both $A$ and $B$ have finite nullity?

I've tried googling it but didn't find anything, I believe that if this is true then it should be known. Also, if this isn't true, and you know how it fails, please do tell me how. Thanks in advance!

Edit: I think this is true, may anyone please check my proof?

Let $\Nul(B) = n$ and $\Nul(A) = m$ and $\mathcal B = \{\alpha_1,\ldots, \alpha_n, \beta_1, \ldots, \beta_m, \ldots\}$ be a basis of $V$, with $\ker(B) = \langle\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n\rangle$ and $\ker(A) = \langle\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_m\rangle$.

Clearly $ABv = 0$ is equivalent to $Bv \in \langle\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_m\rangle$. We can now suppose by contradiction that there exists $\gamma_1, \ldots, \gamma_{m+1} \in \mathcal B\setminus\{\alpha_1,\ldots, \alpha_n\}$ such that $B\gamma_i \in \ker(A)$. However the set $\{B\gamma_1, \ldots, B \gamma_{m+1}\}$ can't be linearly independent as there are more elements than the Nullity of A. This means that $a_1 B \gamma_1 + \cdots + a_{m+1} B\gamma_{m+1} = 0$ for some coefficients (not all zero) $a_i$. By linearity we have that $B(\sum a_i \gamma_i) = 0$ and so $\sum a_i \gamma_i \in \ker(B) = \langle \alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_n\rangle$. In particular this means that the set $\{\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n, \gamma_1, \ldots, \gamma_{m+1}\}$ is not linearly independent and so $\mathcal B$ isn't a basis of $V$, which is a contradiction and so we have the desired inequality.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I didn't get any notification about deleted comments...? Or otherwise I don't understand what you mean. It's fine though, don't worry. I'm writing a motivation letter and I wanted to include a connection between constant coefficient linear differential equations and linear algebra I found interesting, and I wanted to make sure this result was correct so I don't make a fool of myself haha.

Comment: It means you didn't see the comments before I deleted them. No worries.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin oh okay, you don't have to delete the comments, I don't mind. Also, that was a pretty fast reply haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument has a problem, which is that you do not know that $\{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n,\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_m\}$ is linearly independent, so you do not know that you can extend that to a basis. To see the problem, just consider the case of $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$, with $A(x,y,z,\ldots) = (0,0,z,\ldots)$, and $B(x,y,z,w,\ldots) = (x,0,0,w,\ldots)$. Then a basis for $\ker(A)$ is $(1,0,0,\ldots), (0,1,0,\ldots)$; a basis for $\ker(B)$ is $(0,1,1,0,\ldots), (0,0,1,0\ldots)$, and your set $\mathcal{B}$ now contains $(1,0,0,\ldots,), (0,1,0,\ldots), (0,1,1,0,\ldots), (0,0,1,0,\ldots)$ which is linearly dependent; these four vectors cannot be extended to a basis. (This already fails in finite dimension, so the argument wouldn't work for that case).  You have to be more careful; for instance, along the lines of what I do below: rather than taking a basis for all of $\ker(A)$, you should only take a basis for $\ker(A)\cap \mathrm{Im}(B)$).

The statement is correct nonetheless.

If we define the nullity as the dimension of the nullspace, which is the cardinality (finite or infinite) of any basis of the nullspace, then the inequality is true in any space, finite or infinite dimensional, with $A$ and $B$ of finite or infinite nullity. The key is the following:

**Proposition.** Let $T\colon V\to W$ be a linear transformation, and let $S\subseteq V$. If $T$ is one-to-one on $S$, and $T(S)$ is linearly independent in $W$, then $S$ is linearly independent in $V$.

*Proof.* Let $s_1,\ldots,s_n\in S$ be pairwise distinct, and $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\in V$ be such that $\alpha_1s_1+\cdots+\alpha_ns_n = \mathbf{0}_{V}$. Applying $T$ we obtain
$$\alpha_1T(s_1)+\cdots + \alpha_nT(s_n)=\mathbf{0}_{W}.$$
Because $T$ is one-to-one on $S$, the vectors $T(s_1),\ldots,T(s_n)$ are distinct vectors in $T(S)$, and since we are assuming that $T(S)$ is linearly independent, it follows that $\alpha_1=\cdots=\alpha_n=0$, as desired. $\Box$

Let $A,B\in\mathrm{End}(V)$, with $\dim(\ker(A)) = \kappa$, and $\dim(\ker(B))=\mu$. Let $\{v_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a basis for $\mathrm{Im}(B)\cap\ker(A)$; note that $|I|\leq\kappa$. For each $i$, let $w_i\in B$ be such that $T(w_i)=v_i$. Now note that by the Proposition, $\{w_i\}_{i\in I}$ is linearly independendent in $V$. Let $\{z_m\}_{m\in\mu}$ be a basis for $\ker(B)$. I claim that the span of $\{w_i\}_{i\in I}\cup\{z_m\}_{m\in \mu}$ contains $\ker(AB)$.

Indeed, let $x\in\ker(AB)$. Then $A(Bx)=\mathbf{0}$, so $B(x)\in\mathrm{Im}(B)\cap\ker(A)$. Therefore, there exist $i_1,\ldots,i_r\in I$ pairwise distinct, and scalars $a_1,\ldots,a_r$ such that
$$ B(x) = a_1v_{i_1} + \cdots + a_rv_{i_r}.$$
Let $y = a_1w_{i_1}+\cdots + a_rw_{i_r}$. Note that $y\in\mathrm{span}(\{w_i\}_{i\in I})$.

By construction, $B(y) = a_1v_{i_1}+\cdots + a_rv_{i_r} = B(x)$, so $B(x-y)=B(x)-B(y) = \mathbf{0}$. Therefore, $x-y\in\ker(B) = \mathrm{span}(\{z_m\}_{m\in\mu})$. Thus, both $y$ and $x-y$ lie in $\mathrm{span}(\{w_i\}_{i\in I}\cup \{z_m\}_{m\in\mu})$, and therefore so does $x=(x-y)+y$.

This proves that $\ker(AB)\subseteq \mathrm{span}(\{w_i\}_{i\in I}\cup\{z_m\}_{m\in\mu})$. Therefore,
$$\begin{align*}
\dim(\ker(AB))&\leq \dim(\mathrm{span}(\{w_i\}_{i\in I}\cup\{z_m\}_{m\in\mu})\\
&\leq |I|+\mu\\
&\leq \kappa+\mu\\
&= \dim(\ker(A)) + \dim(\ker(B)).
\end{align*}$$
This proves the desired inequality.

In fact, it is clear that $\ker(AB)=\mathrm{span}(\{w_i\}_{i\in I}\cup\{z_m\}_{m\in \mu})$, since $B(w_i)=y_i\in\ker(A)$ and $B(z_m)=\mathbf{0}\in\ker(A)$, giving the other inclusion. You can strengthen the inequality: in fact we have
$$\dim(\ker(AB)) = \dim(\ker(A)\cap\mathrm{Im}(B))+\dim(\ker(B)).$$
To verify this, we just note that our set $\{w_i\}_{i\in I}\cup\{z_m\}_{m\in\mu}$ is linearly independent. Let
$$a_{1}w_{i_1}+\cdots + a_{r}w_{i_r} + b_{1}z_{m_1}+\cdots + b_tz_{m_t} = \mathbf{0}$$
be a linear combination of pairwise distinct vectors in the set that is equal to $\mathbf{0}$. Applying $B$ we obtain
$$a_1v_{i_1}+\cdots + a_rv_{i_r} = \mathbf{0},$$
and the fact that the $w_{i_j}$ were pairwise distinct and that the $v_i$ are linearly independent gives $a_1=\cdots_r=0$. Then we have
$$b_1z_{m_1}+\cdots + b_{t}z_{m_t}=\mathbf{0},$$
and since the $z_m$ are linearly independent, this gives $b_1=\cdots=b_t=0$, as desired. This proves that $\dim(\ker(AB)) = |I|+\mu = \dim(\ker(A)\cap\mathrm{Im}(B)) + \dim(\ker(B))$, as claimed.

Comment: Do you mean the dimension of the nullspace right at the beginning of your proof?

Comment: @TC159: Yes, the cardinality of a basis/dimenions.

Comment: oh alright, thanks